# See data that an app is secretly sending to web server in the background

Tags: tcp, port, monitoring, fiddler, web-traffic

I was playing around with fiddler (http proxy) and I noticed that some apps are making http get/post requests in the background and sending data and stats to and from the web.  This got me interested and a little concerned to see what data various apps were sending but it seems that most of them are not doing it on port 80 via http  but presumably on another port so you can't see the data in fiddler.  Is there some way to view and/or potentially block the data being sent?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking: "Using Fiddler, I saw that traffic was being sent by clients to servers. How can I see that traffic?"

Might I suggest you use Fiddler?

You can see the process sending the traffic in the **Process** column, and you can view the contents of the requests and responses using the **Inspectors** tab.

Comment: As I said most apps do not use port 80 so you see nothing in fiddler.  I meant that the data that some apps are sending does not show up in fiddler so I wondered how it was being sent and how to view it? I assumed it must be on some other port other than port 80 so that is why it is not visible in fiddler so i was wondering how to see it?

Comment: Fiddler doesn't care at all what port the target uses. Your question says you were "playing around with Fiddler" and "noticed some apps" which implies that you did, in fact, see the data inside Fiddler. Maybe you need to revise your question for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out burp suite. It is a proxy you set up in your web browser and shows all of the data that passes through it. There's plenty of tutorials online. Check it out [here](http://portswigger.net/burp/)